# pylint ignores .pylintrc when run from TextMate

Tags: python, textmate, pylint

I'm trying to get pylint to give html output when I run Validate syntax on a python file in TextMate. I installed pycheckmate, pylint, and created a .pylintrc file in $HOME that sets the output format to html.

In TextMate's Advanced control panel, in the Shell Variables tab, I have `TM_PYCHECKER` set to `/usr/local/share/python/pylint`. If I trigger Validate Syntax, it runs pylint with all the default options, and gives me the output. If I change `TM_PYCHECKER` to `/usr/local/share/python/pylint --rcfile "$HOME/.pylintrc"` and Validate Syntax again, I get:

> Please install PyChecker, PyFlakes or Pylint for more extensive code
>   checking.

If I run /usr/local/share/python/pylint from the commandline, without any arguments, the output is html, so I know in that case that it's reading the rcfile. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I found the problem: pycheckmate sets `--output-format=parseable'` as a forced argument to pylint. I found this out by replacing /usr/local/share/python/pylint with a wrapper script that printed out its arguments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from pylint import lint

print sys.argv[1:]
lint.Run(sys.argv[1:])
```

And when I ran it in TextMate I saw this:

```
['--output-format=parseable', '/Users/smithm5/test.py']
test.py:26 [C] Line too long (90/80)
…
```

So I dug into /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Bundles/Python.tmbundle/Support/bin/pycheckmate.py itself. Sure enough, it adds that argument, as well as a *whole lot* of hard-coded html. So to fix it, I removed all the `escape()` wrappers, set `opts = ()` on line 287 so I could set my own darn opts, and changed line 332 to `print line`.

Comment: I love this argprinting drop-in pylint replacement; it was very useful in debugging a related problem today.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat educated guess: try replacing `$HOME` by the absolute path to your home directory.  Shell variables like `$HOME` are probably not available to use in TextMate's control panel.

UPDATE: Looking at the `pycheckmate.py` script included with the `Python.tmbundle` included with the version of TextMate I have, it appears that it is not possible to include arguments , like `--rcfile /path/to/rcfile`.  The value of `TM_PYCHECKER` is expected to only be the path to the checker binary with no arguments.  But, if you make your own copy of the Python.tmbundle, you should be able to edit `pycheckmate.py` to do as you wish.

Comment: Sadly, that did not change the behavior of TextMate. :(